# How do I find the second derivative of $\frac{x}{x-1}$?

Tags: derivatives

I keep on reaching my solution as $2x-2$. Now, here is the thing: I can only solve this using the product, power, and quotient rules, no chain rule. Could someone please explain?

Edit: I forgot about the $g(x)^2$ in the quotient rule. I have now reached the correct answer, thank you for your help.

Comment: Add your solution in an [edit](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1500247/edit) so that it can be checked on errors.

Comment: Hint:  you might find it easier to rewrite the function as $f(x)=1+\frac 1{x-1}$.

Comment: What would I gain by rewriting it?

Comment: Try differentiating your original function and then try differentiating the rewritten form lulu provides. You'll see that advantage. (One requires more work with the quotient rule; the other is a more straightforward application of the chain rule)

Comment: How do I differentiate lulu's equation? Is it using the power rule or what?

Comment: Just quotient rule

Comment: @Dr.MV Problem Statement Question (sorry for the lingo). For some context: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9558/question-about-psq-and-answering-them And for some more global perspective: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9504/what-is-math-se

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the quotient rule, we have

$$\begin{align}
\frac{d\frac{x}{x-1}}{dx}&=\frac{(x-1)\frac{dx}{dx}-x\frac{d(x-1)}{dx}}{(x-1)^2}\\\\
&=\frac{-1}{(x-1)^2}
\end{align}$$

Now, applying the quotient rule a second time yields

$$\begin{align}
\frac{d\frac{-1}{(x-1)^2}}{dx}&=\frac{(x-1)^2\frac{d(-1)}{dx}-(-1)\frac{d(x-1)^2}{dx}}{(x-1)^4}\\\\
&=\frac{(x-1)^2\times (0)+1\times 2(x-1)}{(x-1)^4}\\\\
&=\frac{2}{(x-1)^3}
\end{align}$$

Comment: I just answered your query in a comment to the main question. (That our previous conversation, nowhere offensive or rude or whatever, was seen as fit to be deleted is typical of some fraction of the users of the site.)

Answer (score 2):

Consider
$$\frac{x}{x-1} = \frac{(x-1) + 1}{x-1} = 1 + \frac{1}{x-1}$$
for which
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx} \, \left( \frac{x}{x-1} \right) &= \frac{d}{dx} \left(1 + \frac{1}{x-1} \right) \\
&= 0 - \frac{1}{(x-1)^{2}} \, \left[ (x-1)*\frac{d(1)}{dx} + (1)*\frac{d(x-1)}{dx} \right] \\
&= -\frac{1}{(x-1)^2}
\end{align}
Now applying the same process
\begin{align}
\frac{d^2}{dx^2} \, \left(\frac{x}{x-1}\right) &= - \frac{1}{(x-1)^{4}} \, \left[ (x-1)^{2} * \frac{d(1)}{dx} - (1) * \frac{d(x-1)^{2}}{dx} \right] \\
&= \frac{2(x-1)}{(x-1)^{4}} = \frac{2 \, (x-1)}{(x-1)^{3}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Using the quotient rule,
\begin{equation}
\dfrac d{dx} \dfrac x {x-1} = \dfrac {\dfrac d{dx}(x)\cdot(x-1)-\dfrac {d}{dx}(x-1)\cdot x}{(x-1)^2} = -\dfrac {1}{(x-1)^2} = -\dfrac {1}{x^2-2x+1}
\end{equation}

Then, using the quotient rule again,

\begin{align}
\dfrac {d^2}{dx^2} \dfrac x {x-1} &= \dfrac d{dx} \left(\dfrac d{dx} \dfrac x {x-1}\right) \\
&= \dfrac d{dx} \left(-\dfrac {1}{x^2-2x+1}\right) \\
&= - \dfrac {\dfrac d{dx}(1)\cdot(x^2-2x+1)-\dfrac {d}{dx}(x^2-2x+1)\cdot 1}{(x^2-2x+1)^2} \\
&= - \dfrac {-2x+2}{(x^2-2x+1)^2} \\
&=  \dfrac {2(x-1)}{(x-1)^4} \\
&=  \dfrac {2}{(x-1)^3} 
\end{align}

*Done*

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for.